# Characterization of non-isomorphic graphs but isomorphic total graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, isomorphism-testing

Given a graph $G$, the *total graph of $G$*, denoted $T(G)$, is the graph with vertex set $V(G) \cup E(G)$, where $a$ and $b$ are adjacent in $T(G)$ if and only if they are adjacent or incident in $G$.

> Is there any characterization of properties of two graphs $G$ and $H$ such that $T(G)$ is isomorphic to $T(H)$?

Cross-posted at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633038/characterization-of-non-isomorphic-graphs-but-isomorphic-total-graphs).

Comment: I edited the question to include the definition of a total graph.  Note that it is usually discouraged to cross post on both sites without giving proper time to answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not difficult to see that both $G$ and $L(G)$ are disjoint induced subgraphs of the graph $T(G)$. For your question, in the below paper:

[1] M. Behzad and H. Radjavi, The total group of a graph, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.
19 (1968), 158-163. MR 36 #1358.

It is proved that, the graph $G$ is isomorphic to the graph $H$ if and only if $T(G)$ is isomorphic to $T(H)$.